# MySQL error message

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ubuntu, exception

I have a small issue here. When I go to Startup/ShutDown screen in MySQL workbench, following error message is displayed.(Please refer the image)

[image]

I cannot stop the server when I press the Stop Server button.

My Operating System is Ubuntu 16.04. Any help regarding this is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What version of MySQL Workbench are you using?

Comment: Hi hot2use, 

Thanks for the reply. It is 5.7.17

Comment: Does your MySQL instance name contain any special characters that could be interpreted as a delimiter? _ , ; @ <space> Or are you using a special language encoding / character set?

Comment: No special characters,encoding or character sets are used.

Comment: I guess you mean your MySQL version is 5.7.17 and not MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Sorry about that. It is 6.3.6. And thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are encountering has been previously stored in the [MySQL bug tracking system](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85807) as

> Bug #85807 Shutting down server: Unhandled exception

The recommendation is to upgrade MySQL Workbench to version 6.3.9 as it has been solved in that version:

> ...
>   [6 Apr 0:34] Miguel Solorzano
>   Please try version 6.3.9. Thanks.
>
> [6 Apr 5:17] Shaun Henderson
>   Resolved using version 6.3.9
>   ...

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply hot2use. I will try and post the result :)